# Google Play Achievements List / Gamerscore

Tags: achievements, google-play-games

I've been trying to find a list of my combined Google achievements.

I know I can see a list of the ones I have within each game but I'm wondering if it is possible to see a list of all my achievements across all my games anywhere, like you can for PlayStation and Xbox Live?

Comment: Since asking the question, Google Play Games have implemented Levels and Experience. More details here: https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/3129940?hl=en-GB

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.play.games) to track your Google achievements across all of the games that use them.

Comment: Thanks, didn't realize it showed the achievements in the Google Play app (makes sense tho!)... Not exactly what I was after (as I said I wanted something that combines them), e.g. You've unlocked X achievements over Y games, so can't accept it as an answer. +1 tho

Comment: Hm. I don't think something like that exists at the moment. Will update if I find something, though.

Comment: Thanks idan, if I had time (and any programming experience at all with Android), I might have a shot at making something, but as I have neither... ;)